# Retrieve French language translation in Dynamics CRM using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, plugins, dynamics-crm, crm

Is there a way to get the French value from the translations file in CRM using JavaScript?

So for example, let's say the page is in English and when the user selects a value from an option set, I want to retrieve the French value from the translations file and populate it on the form. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Of course this is possible using Javascript and the OData endpoint.

See [MSDN: Query metadata using the Web API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt607522.aspx) and [Query metadata of Global OptionSet](http://syednizamsyed.blogspot.nl/2016/02/query-metadata-of-global-optionset.html).